# python: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Tags: python

I have this piece of code:

```
def separate_sets(self):
    self.groups = {}
    self.group_names = list(set(self.y))
    if len(self.group_names) > 2:
        print ('more than two classes provided...exiting')
        sys.exit()
    #putting all the samples in a regular order so that their
    #grouping can be easier.
    combined  = sorted(zip(self.x, self.y), key = lambda n: n[1])
    #--doing val,key here because (x,y) was zipped
    for val,key in combined:
        if self.groups.has_key(key):
            self.groups[key].append(val)
        else:
            self.groups[key] = []
            self.groups[key].append(val)
    #train on each group
    self.train()
```

And I received the following error message:

> if self.groups.has_key(key):
>
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Comment: What about the error is not clear? [`has_key` was deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key). Are you using Python 3 by any chance?

Answer (score 16):

In Python 3.x, `has_key()` was removed, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins). Hence, you have to use `in`, which is the pythonic way:

```
if key in self.groups:
```

Answer (score 4):

In python you could use "in" to check

```
 if key in self.groups:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate the whole `if` statement by using the `setdefault` method

```
    self.groups.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
```

Comment: oh, you mean the whole 'if' to 'else' ?

Comment: Yes. `setdefault` returns a reference to `self.groups[key]`, or `[]` if `key` isn't in the `dict`. Either way, you can then add `val` to the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

As of [python 3.x has_key was removed](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins), now you have to use the in operator

Comment: Did you not see the other 2 answers with identical content?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ posted same time  as the Óscar López answer ;)