# Robotframework: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Tags: python, flutter, appium, robotframework

I am new on robotframework automating testing, where I try to test my flutter apps, but got this error when I run the test case

```
    *** Settings ***
    Documentation    Suite description
    Library         AppiumLibrary

    *** Variables ***
    ${APPIUM_SERVER}=       http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
    ${ANDROID_PLAT_NAME}=   Android
    ${ANDROID_PLAT_VER}=    9.0
    ${DEVICE_NAME}=         sopniz6l65qsysyt
    ${PACKET_NAME}=         com.microfabrix.onboarding
    ${ACTIVITY_NAME}=       com.microfabrix.onboarding.MainActivity
    ${fullReset}=           false
    ${noReset}=             true

    *** Test Cases ***
    Test title
        [Tags]    DEBUG
        Provided precondition
        When action
        Then check expectations

    Login
        open application    ${APPIUM_SERVER}        platformName=${ANDROID_PLAT_NAME}        platformVersion=${ANDROID_PLAT_VER}     deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}       automationName=Appium      appPackage=${PACKET_NAME}       appActivity=${ACTIVITY_NAME}        fullReset=${fullReset}      noReset=${noReset}
        sleep                  3
        click button           id=loginBtn
        sleep                  3
        click button           id=page1Btn
        sleep                  3
```

and the result is

```
    (venv) G:\PyCharm>robot -t Login TestCase/onboarding_test.robot
    ==============================================================================
    Onboarding Test :: Suite description
    ==============================================================================
    Login                                                                 | FAIL |
    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Onboarding Test :: Suite description                                  | FAIL |
    1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
    1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
    ==============================================================================
    Output:  G:\PyCharm\output.xml
    Log:     G:\PyCharm\log.html
    Report:  G:\PyCharm\report.html
```

I am not using any `has_key` on my apps, also not using `in` on my apps code, but got this error.
I use python 3.7 and appiumlibrary, already googled and found some suggestions to downgrade to python 2. but still got same error.

is it because i try to test flutter on robotframework?

this is my log
[image]

Comment: This is already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677977/5967122

Comment: its different, in my code there is no has_key

Comment: btw I use apps from this github to test on robotframework

https://github.com/netfirms/flutter-appium-example

Comment: You do need to provide at least a sample code reproducing the issue, together with the libraries you used.

Comment: edited, maybe it will help

Answer (score 1):

Turns out (for me at least, I've never used the library) this is a known issue - "Click Button keyword doesn't work on python 3"  https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary/issues/255.

The workaround cited in the bug is to use `Click Element`.

On a side note, the library's documentatuon says it officially supports Python 2 only, so expect issues like this.